# Using java neuroph source codes

Tags: java, neural-network

i have tried to use neuroph source code in java to create a neural network of more than two input neurons (precisely three) but it displays an input vector size error. Please what's wrong?.

Comment: If you expect somobody to help, you should at least provide some code for this kind of question. Nobody will guess what you have done and what error you have got.

Comment: If you want help it is better to post all of your source code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)